# NameError: 'exit' is not defined in cx_Freeze python

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

**EDIT**

here's my GUI code:

```
from tkinter import *
import builtins as bi

root = Tk()
root.title("hello worlds")

btn = Button(root, text="hello worlds", command=bi.exit)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and this the setup.py

```
import cx_Freeze as cf
import sys

executable = [cf.Executable("asd.py")]

cf.setup(
    name = "asd",
    executables = executable,
    options = {"build_exe" : {"packages" : ["tkinter"]}}
)
```

when I build the script it works fine but, when i run the executable it's show me an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'exit'
```

also i can't use other builtins funtion and i've tried to redefine the exit function. but it's show me an error too:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: `command=bi.exit` looks like an error because `bi` is undefined,

Comment: were you trying to do `command=root.destroy` while trying to exit?

Comment: yes, i want to use that but, why i cant use the exit() function?

Comment: Maybe `builtins` uses C/C++ library which wasn't added to `.exe` automatically and you may have to add it manually in setup. But `tkinter` has `destroy` to close GUI - it can clean memory, etc. but `exit` may not do this. BTW: did you try `exit` instead of `bi.exit` ?

Comment: Yes , I've tried exit before i use bi.exit but it throw an NameError: 'exit' is not defined also i've added manually on setup but still its not working at all :(